# how to insert data from one table to other table in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables t1 and t2 and I want to get data from t1 and insert into the t2.

t1

```
id  amount   cId   nameC open 
10L 100000  CL-J   Jon    0
10L 100000  CL-J   Jon    0
10L 100000  CL-A   Alina  0
10L 100000  CL-A   Alina  0
10L 100000  CL-H   Harry  0
```

t2

```
 cId   nameC balance
  CL-J   Jon    5000
  CL-A   Alina  10000
  CL-H   Harry  4000
  CL-M   Mia    0
```

I want Result like this After insert data in t1

```
  id  amount   cId   nameC open 
    10L 100000  CL-J   Jon    0
    10L 100000  CL-J   Jon    0
    10L 100000  CL-A   Alina  0
    10L 100000  CL-A   Alina  0
    10L 100000  CL-H   Harry  0
    10L 100000  CL-J   Jon    5000
    10L 100000  CL-A   Alina  10000
    10L 100000  CL-H   Harry  4000
```

Comment: insert INTO t1 (Open) SELECT balanc FROM t2 WHERE t2.idCl = t1.idClient

Answer (score 0):

You can move data from one table to another by using `INSERT INTO .. SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO T1(id, amount, cId, nameC, open)
SELECT '10L'
    , 100000
    , cId
    , nameC
    , open
FROM t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM t1 
                  WHERE t1.id = '10L'
                      AND t1.Amount = 100000
                      AND t1.cId = t2.cId
                      AND t1.nameC = t2.nameC
                      AND t1.open = t2.open)
    AND ( t2.NameC <> 'Alina' AND t2.cId <> 'CL-M' AND t2.open <> 0)
    AND ( t2.NameC <> 'John Snow' AND t2.cId <> 'CL-JS' AND t2.open <> 0)
    AND ... -- other conditions here
```

Ideally you'd have a `WHERE` condition which filters the data how you need it and also makes sure that you don't accidentally insert the same data twice, by using a `NOT EXISTS` statement.

Comment: I think a where clause should be there in this query as he does not want to include mia in the final result.

Comment: @radu this query also add the Mia balance I don't want this.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu if t2 have many different records not just Mia

Comment: @Ali Then you need to add more conditions, take a look at my updated query